# AnySlider goTo(slide) using text link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, slider

I am trying to use AnySlider (http://jwilsson.github.io/AnySlider/) with a text link to call specific slides. Unfortunately, I can not get this API function to work:

```
 var slider = $("#slider").data('anyslider');
 slider.goTo(3);
```

Here is the rest of the code. 
Thanks for your help!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.anyslider.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  $('.slider').anyslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        interval: 10000,
        reverse: false,
        showControls: true,
        startSlide: 1,
        showBullets: false,
        speed: 800 
   });
});

</script>
 </head>

 <body>

<div class="slider">
    <div>
         <img src="1.jpg" width="500" /><p><br />Slide 1</p>
    </div>

    <div>
         <img src="2.jpg" width="500" /><p><br />Slide 2</p>
    </div>

    <div>
         <img src="3.jpg" width="500" /><p><br />Slide 3</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content" id="content">

 <a href="#" onclick="javascipt: var slider = $("#slider").data('anyslider'); slider.goTo(2); "><strong>Slide 2</strong></a> 

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code references the id (jquery '#') instead of the class (jquery '.') AND it looks like the git info has some issues. The following works (notice the '**anyslider**.goTo()' - not 'slider.goTo()')

```
var slider = $('.slider').anyslider();
var anyslider = slider.data('anyslider');

anyslider.goTo(2);
```

OR

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: var slider = $('.slider').anyslider(); var anyslider = slider.data('anyslider'); anyslider.goTo(2); "><strong>Slide 2</strong></a>
```